# jq read inline string, not from stdin

Tags: json, jq

This can read from a file:

```
jq '.c | fromjson | .id' my_file.json
```

this reads from stdin:

```
echo "$my_json" | jq -r '.field'
```

what if I just want to read from a string like so:

```
jq '.field' "$my_json"
```

how to do that?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

A simple call using `-n` should be enough:

```
jq -nr "${my_json}|.field"
```

example:

```
> jq -nr '{foo: "bar",baz: "test"}|.foo'
bar
```

Comment: nice, I might select this as the answer - can you link to the docs where this is documented?

Comment: This answer uses the shell's string interpolation, which has nothing to do with jq. There are occasions when this technique makes sense, but it depends on the shell you're using.  As a rule, especially on a general Q&A website, the more robust alternatives are to be preferred.

Comment: @MrCholo not sure which part is unclear to you. `-n` makes jq not read any input, just process it's argument. And on the commandline you just define the json object and "pipe" it to the selector ".field" which selects that field.

Comment: @peak I don't see how this answer only uses shell str interpolation, it clearly uses JQ

Comment: @MrCholo - I did not say that the answer as a whole does not use jq.  I said that the answer uses (i.e. relies on) shell interpolation.  You should read up on the shell.  Or put the filter into a file, say filter.jq, and then run `jq -nr -f filter.jq`

Answer (score 10):

You can use a `bash` feature which lets you redirect stdin from a literal string with the `<<<` operator:

```
$ json='{"field": 3}'
$ jq .field <<< "$json"
3
```

It of course also works with inline JSON:

```
$ jq .field <<< '{"field": 3}'
3
```

Comment: something like this would be nice `jq '.field'  -s "$my_json_string"`

Comment: Currently, `jq` does not have a feature like that.  It might be an intentional design decision; according to the UNIX philosophy that "everything is a file," it might be simpler to have a program only accept input on stdin and let the shell handle redirection, instead of in every program implementing all the functionality users might want (read from file, read from keyboard, read from socket, read from literal string, ...)

Comment: not everything is a file but *everything is* a stream of chars imo, and a string arg is just that. nevertheless, MrCholo approves this answer.

Answer (score 9):

```
$ jq -n '$in.foo' --argjson in '{"foo":"bar"}'
"bar"
$ jq -n '$foo' --arg foo 'bar'
"bar"
```

- `-n` to use `null` as input (instead of STDIN),
- `--argjson` for passing a JSON entity (object, array, number, string, boolean or `null`)
- `--arg` for passing a (shell) string.

Answer (score 0):

A third possibility is to read a string from the environment:

```
$ string='{"field": 33}' jq -n '$ENV.string|fromjson.field'
33
```

The fourth (and essentially only other) possibility is to use positional arguments (jq 1.5 and higher):

```
$ jq -n '$ARGS.positional[0]|fromjson.field' --args '{"field": 333}'
333
```

Comment: pretty weird, why not just read env vars with the standard `$xyz` (not blaming you, just the library author). See this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57043296/5047085

Comment: Using the shell's string interpolation has nothing to do with jq or its authors. There are occasions when this technique makes sense, but it can lead to confusion and complications, and not just for Windows users.  One of the many sources of potential complications is that jq has its own "$" variables.